# Does the CS and DS registers still affect instructions in x64 intel

Tags: windows, assembly, kernel, x86-64, memory-segmentation

Afaik they are never used and CS=DS=SS nowadays. However if I were to set these values, would anything change or does the processor ignore them. Ive found really conflicting information on the question and I don't understand why they would still be there if they are ignored. Help pls

Comment: CS=DS=SS for a while now, long before 64-bit OSes. If you are writing user-mode applications, there's little you can do with the selector registers (yet you can still do something, like switching bitness). A kernel, however, can be more creative. x86-64 hardcoded some of the original features of the PM segmentation model. Selectors are not ignored, just easier to use for the dominan use-case. A lot of questions about it are present here on SO, I don't really feel like going down the whole GDT/segmentation thing again. Can you narrow down what exactly is not adding up in the answers you found?

Comment: BTW CS!=DS as CS must select a code segment descriptor. Unless you meant they encompass the same area of memory.

Comment: By that I meant that in x64 processor mode the CS and DS segments are set to 0. I understand how to write the registers, but I was confused about if the processor still takes the registers into account while executing in 64 bit mode. I've seen people saying no it doesn't and I've seen people saying yes it does. If CS=0 normally and I execute call 0x33333333 and I set CS = 1 then execute call 0x33333333 will it take the value of CS into account.

Comment: For example "The x86-64 architecture does not use segmentation in long mode (64-bit mode)." https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation

Comment: @MargaretBloom I'm wondering if in 64 bit mode, does the processor completely ignore the CS value or is it just left at 0, and if it were changed would start affecting calls and etc

Comment: Segmentation is a bit more involved than just the base address and limit (those are the features that I referred to as hardcoded). However the CPU **still** uses the selector registers, for one thing `CS` holds the CPL of the running code. Segments define attributes of memory regions, in 64-bit mode you cannot set a region start and ending address but you still can set the other attributes. "Segmentation" means two things in x86: 1) Segmentation of memory, i.e. having an offset added to every address and a limit check 2) The segmentation subsystem, i.e. the GDT, LDT, IDT, protection rings. ...

Comment: ... Segmentation of memory has been disabled for most of the selector registers. However the segmentation subsystem is still in use. Maybe this ambiguous word is why you are finding different answers.

Comment: The segment *registers* won't be set to `0`, at least not CS.  It has to be a selector that selects a valid GDT or LDT entry.  The segment *base* address is fixed at 0 for all the segments you mentioned (and ES), and ignored when loading the GDT entry.  DS/ES register values can I think be a null selector, i.e. `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the segment registers do still affect code execution.

The question and some of the comments don't seem to distinguish between the selector value and the base address. To clearly understand some of the apparently conflicting information you're reading on this topic, you need to make sure you recognize which one is being discussed.

The CS selector cannot be 0. It must refer to a valid code segment descriptor in the GDT or LDT. The L bit of the code segment descriptor controls whether the current process is 64-bit mode or 32-bit compatibility mode.

CS (the selector) cannot be equal to DS and SS. CS must refer to a code segment, whereas DS and SS must refer to data segments (possibly the same one). The DS and SS selectors are allowed to be 0 (which would cause a GP fault in 32-bit mode).

The main aspect of segment registers that *doesn't* still have an effect is the base address and segment limit; the base address of CS, DS, ES, and SS are all treated as if they are 0, and there are no segment limit checks in 64-bit code.
This is the reason you see people saying that they are ignored.

As Margaret mentioned, the current privilege level (CPL) is in the low 2 bits of the CS and SS selector registers and also in the DPL bits of the descriptors in the GDT. These bits should be either 0 or 3, since no current operating systems use rings 1 and 2, as far as I know.

One other minor point is that certain faults caused by memory accesses are reported as stack faults instead of GP faults, if the memory access is performed using the SS segment (because RBP or RSP is used as a base register in the instruction operand).

Comment: CPL and DPL aren't necessarily equal. This could be the case for a FAR JMP/CALL to a conforming segment. With a conforming segment CPL is unchanged when a transition is made which means that it may not match DPL at all.

Comment: A non-canonical address for an `[rbp]`  addressing mode will be reported as a `#SS` stack fault *even if you use a DS prefix*.  i.e. the prefix is truly ignored.  In [Why is the use of the 'DS:' segment override illegal in 64-bit mode?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50400274) I quoted Intel manual vol.1 3.3.7.1 Canonical Addressing on this: DS and SS segment overrides are truly ignored, according to that.  It goes both ways; both SS and DS prefixes are ignored for determining which kind of fault happened.

Comment: Thanks, this anwsers my question.